# Select camera with Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm  new to the Angular framework and I need to display my function in DOM but I've got a problem that I can't read my function.

The error in  my console

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'deviceInfos' of 
>   undefined

My function is:

```
gotDevices() {
    if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices) {
      console.log("enumerateDevices() not supported.");
      return;
    }

    // List cameras and microphones.

    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
    .then(function(devices) {

      devices.forEach(function(device) {

        console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +
                    " id = " + device.deviceId);
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
    });
}
```

In component `.html`:

```
<select class="form-control Dr_input Dr_select Dr_input_size" (change)="gotDevices()">
    <option  value="{{d}}" *ngFor="let d of devices" >{{d}}</option>

    </select>
```

Comment: You are passing deviceInfo into gotDevices but are never using it in the function. Can you show us more code and where deviceInfo is being used please.

Comment: i  update the code you can check again

Comment: I dont see deviceInfos in your code anymore does it appear anywhere else?

Comment: Can you try execute this code and if you Can find me another way to select camera and display it in front

Answer (score 0):

somethere u try do something like this:

> anything.deviceInfos = ...

but **anything** is undefined

Comment: @slimabdi u try to set property "deviceInfos" to undefined variable... if u use some IDE for develop (like webstorm) try to search something like this ".deviceInfos =" or "['deviceInfos'] =" or with double quotes...

Comment: i use visual studio  my  point for this  exemple to display camera active when  i select device  but nothing appear  :/